# Looking for a good tutorial for developing iPhone apps using .NET and Mono

Tags: .net, iphone, mono

Interested in writing an iPhone app but don't want to buy a mac or learn objective-c.  I was excited to see that you could do this using Mono but haven't found too many resources out there.

Does anyone know of any good online tutorials for writing your first iPhone app using Mono?

Comment: http://monotouch.net/Documentation ?

Comment: Note that MonoTouch will not get you out of the requirement of using a Mac for development.  From their FAQ: "MonoTouch requires a Mac and Apple's iPhone SDK to test on the emulator and deploy on the device. And you will need to be an Apple iPhone developer to deploy on the device."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://monotouch.net/

There are lots of tutorials over there, and I am not aware of any other tool set to do this.

.NET does not run on the iPhone/iPad. According to this [article](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/iphone-gets-net-app-development-194):

> A cross-compiler is included to turn
>   .Net executable files and libraries
>   into native applications for
>   distribution on the Apple App Store or
>   for deployment by enterprise iPhone
>   users. Ahead-of-time compilation is
>   used instead of a Just In Time
>   compiler, enabling distribution in the
>   Apps Store.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not referring to the mono IDE on linux, but rather the monotouch application by Novell, a good starting place would be their tutorial section:

http://monotouch.net/Tutorials

Alternatively, if you were looking to develop .Net applications directly for iOS, it is not yet possible according to Wikipedia:

"The applications[iOS applications] must be written and compiled specifically for iOS and the ARM architecture."